# Why does && in Ruby sometimes shortcut evaluates and sometimes doesnt?

Tags: ruby

I want to test if an element in a hash exists and if it is >= 0, then put true or false into an array:

```
boolean_array << input['amount'] && input['amount'] >= 0
```

This raises no >= on NilClass error. However, if I just do this:

```
input['amount'] && input['amount'] >= 0   #=> false
```

No problem. Basically:

```
false && (puts 'what the heck?') #=> false
arr = []
arr << false && (puts 'what the heck?') #=> stdout: 'what the heck?'
arr #=> [false]
```

What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently it's being grouped as:

```
(boolean_array << input['amount']) && input['amount'] >= 0
```

Try:

```
boolean_array << (input['amount'] && input['amount'] >= 0)
```

However, if it ends up being false, the expression returns `nil`, so you want:

```
boolean_array << (!input['amount'].nil? && input['amount'] >= 0)
```

Answer (score 6):

`<<` has more precedence than `&&`. See [Ruby Operator Precedence](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence).

Answer (score 5):

`&&` is always evaluated short circuit in Ruby.

The problem is  `<<` is before `&&` in precedence, see [Rubydoc:precedence](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html)

So the line

```
arr << false && (puts 'what the heck?')
```

is actually:

```
(arr << false) && (puts 'what the heck?')
```